# React Native Navigation: Remove screen from stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation 5.

At the top I have a Drawer navigator, with the following screens:

```
  <Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen name="One" component={StackNavigatorOne} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Two" component={StackNavigatorTwo} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Three" component={StackNavigatorThree} />
  <Drawer.Navigator/>
```

Within `StackNavigatorOne`, I have a stack navigator,

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen3} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

When user clicks `StackNavigatorOne` from the drawer, the user goes to `Screen 1` of `StackNavigatorOne`. From Screen 1, the user is taken to `Screen2` after a few seconds.

Once the user has reached `Screen2`, I want to completely remove `Screen 1` from `StackNavigatorOne`, so that the next time when user clicks `StackNavigatorOne` in drawer, there is no `Screen1` now, and the user is directly taken to `Screen2`. Is this possible? Can you please help?

Comment: You can set a global state could be through redux or context. And when the screen 1 is displayed once, you can set this state to true, like isScreenOneDisplayed={true}. And in your Stack navigator, based on this state, you can render the screens that you want. I can give you more details if that is not clear enough.

Comment: This solution will work for me. I'm using redux. So, I should render the screens conditionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since you are using React Navigation 5, you can render your stacks or screens conditionally.
For example;

```
<Stack.Navigator>
 { !isScreenOneDisplayed && <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} /> }
  <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```